# How to convert a date String into the right format in Java?

Tags: java, string, datetime

Can somebody please explain to me how I can convert

**2009-10-27 14:36:59.580250**

into

**27.10.2009, 14:36** ?

The first date is available as a string and the second one should be a string as well ;) Up to now I'm not so into date conversion within Java...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for this. First step is to parse the first string into a `java.util.Date` object using `SimpleDateFormat` based on the pattern of the first string. Next step is to format the obtained `java.util.Date` object into a string based on the pattern of the second string. For example:

```
String datestring1 = "2009-10-27 14:36:59.580250";
Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(datestring1);
String datestring2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm").format(date1);
System.out.println(datestring2);
```

**Edit**: I've removed the `.SSSSSS` part from the first pattern because it failed. But in my opinion it should in theory have worked with `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"` and `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"` as well, but it is calculating them as seconds! I consider this as a buggy implementation in `SimpleDateFormat`. The [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) handles the millis/micros perfectly with those patterns.

Comment: This code definitely does not work as expected. "S" is the format pattern for milliseconds, but the input value obviously contains microseconds, so that the output of the code example will be "27.10.2009 14:46" (it adds 580.250 seconds instead of 0.58250 secs).

Comment: I didn't test it, but you're right about the influence of the micros. Updated answer.

Comment: jarnbjo your right! I did oversee this but now it works ;) Thanks for the hint ^^

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is not buggy, because it parses "580250" as 580250ms with an "SSS" pattern. For number fields, the formatter prints at least the number of digits (0 prefixed) corresponding to the number of pattern characters. When parsing, the number of pattern characters is irrelevant, except for the year field, for which the number of characters has a specific meaning. The patterns "yyy-M-d H:m:s.S" and "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS" are hence identical for the parser.

Comment: OK then I'd call it an unwanted feature :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use SimpleDateFormat. Although there's no format specification for micro-seconds (the last fragment of your input), you can make use of the fact that the parser ignores the rest of the string if it has already managed to match the configured pattern:

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
System.out.println(formatter.format(parser.parse("2009-10-27 14:36:59.580250")));
```

The parser will in this case simply ignore the last part ":59.580250" of the input string.

Comment: But there's indeed none for micros. Oddily the `.SSS` also doesn't work nicely, it still takes the micros into account.

Comment: BalusC: Sorry, this is really embarrasin. I'm ranting over you and am not even able to write my own response properly, mixing up millis and micros. I ment micro, wrote milli and have corrected it now :)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). You can use this to *both parse and format*. I would suggest parsing the above into a [Date](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object using one SimpleDateFormat, and then formatting to a String using a 2nd SimpleDateFormat.

Note that SimpleDateFormat suffers from threading issues, and so if you're using this in a threaded environment, either create new SimpleDateFormats rather than used static versions, or use the corresponding but thread-safe classes in [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Good hint concerning the threading issue. But BalusC got the "accepted" answer since he provided a code example which led me faster to my goal. But thanks as well!

Comment: That's entirely reasonable :-)

Comment: Marcus: Nice of you to accept an answer with a buggy code example, when other people (like me :-/) tried to help you with a correct answer.

Comment: It's worth checking out Joda time btw. Threading aside it parses quicker then the JDK version.

Comment: @jarnbjo - sometimes an answer you see gives you an insight without necessarily being the most *correct*. Don't get hassled by it :-(

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind when you do this that you are losing precision. Depending on your specific application, this may or may not matter.

If you already have the original date saved somewhere, this is not an issue. However, if the source date is from a transient source (e.g., streaming in from a physical sensor of some sort), it may be a good idea to persist the interim Date object (output of SimpleDateFormat#parse(String)) somewhere.

Just thought I'd point that out.