# java code which convert string 18 oct, 2012 format to java utill date

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a date String into the right format in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748883/how-to-convert-a-date-string-into-the-right-format-in-java)

Please tell me the java code to convert a string `18 oct, 2012` format to java utill date and again I want check with mysql database.

Comment: Please google "Java parse date". Or search SO with this. This is a very basic question.

Answer (score 1):

Using SimpleDateFormat

```
String txtdate = "18 oct,2012";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM,yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse(txtdate);
System.out.println(date);
```

prints for me

```
Thu Oct 18 00:00:00 BST 2012
```

as expected.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

// To convert a String Date into any form you want...

String txtdate ="18 oct,2012"
SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy");

Date date = dt.parse(txtdate);

SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
dt1.format(date)
```

Hope that will help you solving your problem..According to your question third line of code will be helpful i guess if i m getting your question right...!!

Comment: -1, your format strings do not match the requested format

Comment: @MARK Sorry, that was a mistake. Its just about parsing it into date format. Rest of no use to the question i guess..Anyways thanks for correcting me..